# Postgres Async API detecting end of query

Tags: sql, c, postgresql, asynchronous

I'm working with the PostgreSQL C API. Reading the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-async.html) it states that a query is finished when PQgetResult returns NULL and PQgetResult will block if PQisBusy does not return 0. However PQisBusy returns 1 if there is no more input, so I can't call PQgetResult and get the NULL. Therefore I can't know if the query is over. Is there any other way to know if the query is done? Did I misunderstand the async API?

----edit-----

The basic idea as C code is:

```
PQsendQuery(conn, query)

while(true)
{
    PQconsumeInput(conn)
    if(PQisBusy(conn) == 0)
    {
        PGresult* res = PQgetResult(conn);
        if(res)
        {
            //print result
        }
        else
        {
            //res == NULL
            //indicates query is over
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

The result will be printed but the loop never terminates. Because PQisBusy only returns 0 once.

Comment: It might be worth fleshing this out with code that shows what you're doing.

Comment: I think PQgetResult checks and waits for busy signal before returning result. So may not require if(PQisBusy(conn) == 0) check at all.

Comment: @MuhammadUsama the point of the code is that it may never block, hence the async. I know that doing async I/O in an busy loop is pointless but I needed an minimal example.

Comment: Does this help? http://postgresql.1045698.n5.nabble.com/How-to-guard-PostgreSQL-from-overcharged-and-or-malicious-read-only-queries-tp3311738p3312327.html

Answer (score 5):

I think what you need is `PQsetSingleRowMode` to let `PQgetResult` return one row each time.

from http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/libpq-single-row-mode.html

> Ordinarily, libpq collects a SQL command's entire result and returns
>   it to the application as a single PGresult. This can be unworkable for
>   commands that return a large number of rows. For such cases,
>   applications can use PQsendQuery and PQgetResult in single-row mode.
>   In this mode, the result row(s) are returned to the application one at
>   a time, as they are received from the server.
>
> If the query returns any rows, they are returned as individual
>   PGresult objects, which look like normal query results except for
>   having status code PGRES_SINGLE_TUPLE instead of PGRES_TUPLES_OK.
>   After the last row, or immediately if the query returns zero rows, a
>   zero-row object with status PGRES_TUPLES_OK is returned; this is the
>   signal that no more rows will arrive.

check out the sample code: 
https://github.com/markokr/libpq-rowproc-demos/blob/master/demo-onerow-async.c

Comment: The sample code you linked to evaluates the return value of PQresultStatus to determine if the query is over. I don't like the style of that, but I guess its the best solution so far. Therefor I will give you the bounty, before it is lost.

Answer (score 1):

Based on what I understood from the link in my comment, I would try something like this (the parameters to `select()` and the other function calls may be quite different):

```
if (select(sock   1, &input_mask, NULL, NULL, NULL) < 0) {

    fprintf(stderr, "select() failed: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    exit_nicely(conn);
}

PQconsumeInput(conn);

while (PQisBusy(conn) != 0) {

    /* wait here */ 

}

while (PGresult* res = PQgetResult(conn)) { /* not sure this is OK, test for not null */

    /* do something with res */

}
```

Comment: This doesn't help. Your code may block since you call PQgetResult in a loop without testing if the connection is busy.

Comment: Since it waits on `PQisBusy()` until it is not busy any more and only then calls `PQgetResult()`, I quite don't think so.  (I may be wrong anyway.)  Have you tried this?

Comment: Unless I completely misunderstood the point of PQsendQuery then a query my be collected in multiple chunks, I.e fragments of a big table. Therefor PQisBusy return 0 does not indicate that the query is over, in that case my question would be mood, it only indicates that some input is available. Validating this code by testing it is actually not a good idea; the code may run non blocking in lab environments but that doesn't guaranty that the code wont block in production.

Comment: I agree with yu on the latter part - and, to be honest, can't convincingly contradict on the former.  Have you considered asking this on the PostgreSQL list the link in my above comment points to?  (If I understood correctly, PQconsumeInput() takes care of collecting the chunks.)

Answer (score 0):

I can see one issue with the code, You are not checking return of PQconsumeInput(conn) function. As it is the responsibility of PQconsumeInput to clear out the busy flag. What could be happening is that PQconsumeInput would be failing without processing any data and clearing out busy flag.

I think checking the result of PQconsumeInput before calling PQisBusy should work fine.

```
while (PQconsumeInput(conn) == 1) 
{
  if(PQisBusy(conn) == 0)
  {
        PGresult* res = PQgetResult(conn);
        if(res)
        {
            //print result
        }
        else
        {
            //res == NULL
            //indicates query is over
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: PQconsumeInput returning 0 indicates a error the documentation specifies that even in a case of an error PQgetResult has to be called until it returns NULL. Also, again, the above code is only a minimalist example. In the real code I do error checking.

Comment: Note: Even when PQresultStatus indicates a fatal error, PQgetResult should be called until it returns a null pointer, to allow libpq to process the error information completely.

Comment: sorry I pushed return too early and now I can't edit my comment, so please ignore the above.
Document says "Even when PQresultStatus indicates a fatal error, PQgetResult should be called until it returns a null pointer, to allow libpq to process the error information completely." So I think it is only valid for error occurred durring PQGetResult function call, not for error occurred in PQconsumeInput. Also in your case you are waiting for PQisBusy to return "not busy" before calling PQGetResult and I believe PQisBusy could not be trusted in case of error returned by PQconsumeInput function.

Comment: I think the following thread may be helpful http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-novice/2011-09/msg00033.php
and example code http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-novice/2011-09/txtcpSnbb_g9C.txt

Comment: Again the example code in my question is an minimalist version that illustrates the problem. In the real production code I use proper error checking and no errors are occurring.